# Check email already exist in the DB

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have below code. This code  only shows second  alert for both exist and non exist emails. Can you please show me where is the error .

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#email").focusout(function(){
  var emailVal = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'check_email.php',
        data:  { 
         myparam:emailVal //set it with a parameter name
      },

        success: function( data ) {
        if(data==1){
            alert("email already exists!");}
            if(data==0){
            alert("email is available!");}
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my check_email.php file. As I guess getting values from php files is faulty.

```
 <?php
  require_once("connnection.php"); 
    $con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    }

    if (isset($_POST['myparam'])){
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['myparam']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
    $select=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("fail");
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($select);

    if ($row >0) {

        return 1;
    }else 
    return 0;

    }
    else
    echo "post error";
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing.

Comment: For both exist and non exist emails, code shows second alert.....

Comment: Concentrate on a single part of this flow - first validate that the server is behaving as you expect and then move onto the client side code. Please don't just jump all your code here for us to deal with - you'll have to do a little bit of debugging yourself first.

Comment: Please add `alert(data)` at the beginning of success function and tell us what does it say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo the result instead of returning it:

```
if ($row >0) {
  echo 1;
}
else {
  echo 0;
}
```

If you just use `return` the value will not be sent back to the browser.

Of course, you could just do

```
echo $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've a curly brace mismatch in your PHP file `if-else` code block

Change From :

```
if ($row >0) {

        return 1;
    }else 
    return 0;

    }
    else
    echo "post error";
```

To

```
if ($row >0) {

        return 1;
    }else 
    {
    return 0;

    }
    else
    echo "post error";
```